# Is it possible to create an issue on Gitlab using command line?

Tags: gitlab, issue-tracking

I was reading up on creating issues on Gitlab and I am wondering if it is possible to create issues using the command line? Thank you

Answer (score 4):

You can use the GitLab CLI https://glab.readthedocs.io/en/latest/issue/create.html

`glab issue create [flags]`

Examples:

```
$ glab issue create
$ glab issue new
$ glab issue create -m release-2.0.0 -t "we need this feature" --label important
$ glab issue new -t "Fix CVE-YYYY-XXXX" -l security --linked-mr 123
$ glab issue create -m release-1.0.1 -t "security fix" --label security --web
```

Answer (score 2):

You can always invoke the GitLab API using any command line HTTP library, like `curl`. You can see examples of this in the [Issues API documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/issues.html).

Example:

```
curl --request POST --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN: <your_access_token>" "https://gitlab.example.com/api/v4/projects/4/issues?title=Issues%20with%20auth&labels=bug"
```

There are also some third-party CLI tools. For example, `python-gitlab` [offers a CLI](https://python-gitlab.readthedocs.io/en/stable/cli-examples.html) (in addition to the Python toolkit). or [glab](https://glab.readthedocs.io/en/latest/issue/create.html) mentioned by Markus.

Ultimately, these tools are simply interacting with the GitLab REST API and are, fundamentally, not much different than using an HTTP client like `curl`, but are certainly a bit more convenient/usable.